# How do I copy pages from Wikipedia using some script?

Tags: perl

I need pages of cities in my country from Wikipedia for use in my website.
For example for [New York](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City) there'll one main page about the city. So if I've a list of cities how do I download the pages?

It is going to be 1000's of cities.

I've also heard that Wikipedia does not like bots accessing it's page.
I'll be using the information as per Creative Commons License.

It'd be nice if I'm able to write the code in a perl script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`WWW::Wikipedia`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aWikipedia):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Wikipedia;

my $wiki  = WWW::Wikipedia->new();
my $entry = $wiki->search('New York');

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
print $entry->fulltext();
```

Read about text returning methods in [`WWW::Wikipedia::Entry`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aWikipedia%3a%3aEntry):

- [`text`](http://search.cpan.org/~bricas/WWW-Wikipedia-2.00/lib/WWW/Wikipedia/Entry.pm#text%28%29)
- [`text_basic`](http://search.cpan.org/~bricas/WWW-Wikipedia-2.00/lib/WWW/Wikipedia/Entry.pm#text_basic%28%29)
- [`fulltext`](http://search.cpan.org/~bricas/WWW-Wikipedia-2.00/lib/WWW/Wikipedia/Entry.pm#fulltext%28%29)
- [`fulltext_basic`](http://search.cpan.org/~bricas/WWW-Wikipedia-2.00/lib/WWW/Wikipedia/Entry.pm#fulltext_basic%28%29)
- [`raw`](http://search.cpan.org/~bricas/WWW-Wikipedia-2.00/lib/WWW/Wikipedia/Entry.pm#raw%28%29)

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't scrape Wikipedia when they offer the data freely for download:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

And tips on how to use it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Help_parsing_dumps_for_use_in_scripts

Then you can simply use the tools that have already been made available to you:

http://search.cpan.org/dist/MediaWiki-DumpFile

Alternatively, if you really do want just a known, limited subset, there is an API available:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API

To use that with perl you'd start looking at the LWP and JSON modules, or, again, leverage CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/dist/MediaWiki-API

Comment: Also the `Special:Export` page.

Comment: This is documented at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_Special:Export.